# bundletool universal apk module not found

Tags: android, android-studio

In my project I got some dynamic features (split apks). to make testing easier I am trying to create a universal apk that contains all features. To achieve that I am using bundletool to create a universal "fat" apk. When installing the app from Android studio everything works fine, the problem I'm currently facing is that for some reason the dynamic module can't be found when installing the universal apk.

here is how I attempt to load a class from the dynamic module (works when installing from studio)

```
Class moduleClass = Class.forName("com.mydomain." + moduleName + "." + 
moduleName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + moduleName.substring(1) + "Module");
                        Constructor constructor = moduleClass.getConstructor(Context.class, IModuleCallback.class);
```

here is how I create universal apk

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=service-stub-debug.aab --output=myapp.apks --mode=universal
```

I then unzip the apks output file to get the universal apk. Why is it that in universal apk the class name can't be found ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

it turned out i was missing this line in my dynamic module manifest

Comment: Can you please add the line you were missing? Until you've done that, this should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: you mean this line?
<dist:fusing dist:include="true"/>